# Is there a way to turn off the profanity filter on Word's *Transcribe* (not Dictate) functionality?

Tags: microsoft-word, transcription

I am wondering if there is a way by which the profanity filter can be disabled on Word's Transcribe functionality.

I know that the feature exists for Dictate.  However, as far as I can tell, turning it off there seems to have no effect on audio flies submitted via the 'Transcribe' option.

I don't think it matters, but at the moment, this is using the 'Transcribe' choice within the Word EXE file, rather than trying it in the browser.